# Why does my code return the error "missing : after property id" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

How is this supposed to be written so that it would actually work?

```
saveBuyerInfo( 
    { 'save_'+$("#textAreaXMLPostRequest").attr('name') :
    $("#textAreaXMLPostRequest").val() } );
```

Comment: What's the problem with that?

Comment: @Seb — He's trying to use an expression on the left-hand side.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't have an expression as the key in an object literal. Instead, create your object first:

```
var save = {};
save['save_' + $("#textAreaXMLPostRequest").attr('name')] = $("#textAreaXMLPostRequest").val();
saveBuyerInfo(save);
```

Comment: It's a shame, really. I was just looking for an unanswered question to test a Greasemonkey script on, without answering. Just my luck that it turned out to be something I knew! ;-)