# Why can't one object's property value be used as a property name in another object?

Tags: javascript

The following gives me an error in my JS console (firebug):

```
var obj1 = {name:'king', val:20}, obj2, objName = obj1.name;
obj2 = {obj1.name:obj1.val};
```

But the following works just fine:

```
var obj1 = {name:'king', val:20}, obj2, objName = obj1.name;
obj2 = {objName:obj1.val};
```

The exact error is: "missing : after property id".  I don't need a work-around, I'm curious to know what the problem is here.

Comment: those variable declarations hurt my eyes....

Answer (score 5):

Expressions aren't allowed left of ':' inside of object literals.

Please have a look here: [Why does my code return the error "missing : after property id" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664166/why-does-my-code-return-the-error-missing-after-property-id-in-javascript) and here http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/obj_lit.php

Comment: But you can always get around that by using `[]` if you don't mind a bit more noise and busy work during initialization: `var obj2 = { }; obj2[obj1.name] = obj1.val;`.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used JS for a while, so correct if I'm wrong

If you use this:

```
obj = {name : value};
```

then you are creating a new object with a new field called `name`.

So when you tried to do

```
obj2 = {obj1.name : obj1.val};
```

you were attempting to create a field called `obj1.name`, which is not a valid identifer.

For the second one

```
obj2 = {objName : obj1.val};
```

the name `objName` is a valid identifier, so this works. But it is not using the variable `objName`, but is creating a *new* one as a field for `obj2`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confused about why the 2nd one works.

```
var obj1 = {name:'king', val:20}, obj2, objName = obj1.name;
obj2 = {objName:obj1.val};
```

The name of the property in `obj2` won't actually be "king." It will be "objName" -- just the string "objName" not the value of the variable `objName`.

If you want to dynamically assign property names, it's pretty simple.

```
var obj1 = {name:'king', val:20}, obj2;
obj2 = {};
obj2[obj1.name]=obj1.val;
```